# xarray - Return data that meets certain criteria without having to use for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I am working with multi-dimensional data `da_criteria_1or0_hourly`.

The data (variable) is either 1 or 0.

```
print(da_criteria_1or0_hourly)
```

Output:

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 8760, latitude: 106, longitude: 193)>
dask.array<shape=(8760, 106, 193), dtype=int32, chunksize=(744, 106, 193)>
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 ... -33.950478 -33.9
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01 ... 2017-12-31T23:00:00
```

The data is as massive as 179212080.

I am unsure which method on xarray I should use to get a new xarray object that only return data which is `1` (`0` can be assigned NaN or dropped).

I was trying to print out data for each coordinate using `sel` using FOR LOOP, but this was extremely slow. It could take forever.

```
for time_elem in da_criteria_1or0_hourly.coords['time'].values:
    for lat_elem in da_criteria_1or0_hourly.coords['latitude'].values:
        for lon_elem in da_criteria_1or0_hourly.coords['longitude'].values:
            val = da_criteria_1or0_hourly.sel(time=time_elem,latitude=lat_elem,longitude=lon_elem).values
            if (val == 1):
                print(time_elem, lat_elem, lon_elem, val)
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly `xarray.Dataset.where` should be the way to go:

```
da_criteria_1or0_hourly.where(da_criteria_1or0_hourly == 1)
```

This will return a new xarray where every entry that was not 1 is now NaN.

**Time comparison for a 50x50x50 xarray:**

for loops: ~56.9456s

`where`: ~00.0020s